# DrawString from RichTextbox include formating (Bold,Italic,Align) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to DrawString with the text from RichTextbox,
I done it, but the text formating like Bold, Italic, and Align is not drawn.

```
Private Sub PictureBox4_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Paint
    Dim newImage As Image = Panel1.BackgroundImage
    Dim fontt As New Font("Tahoma", 10)
    Dim format As New StringFormat
    format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 0, 0)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, fontt, Brushes.Silver, 10, 10)
End Sub
```

I use `PictureBox4_Paint` to draw the string when the form load.
Please help

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to create the `Font` with the appropriate [`FontStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx), e.g.

```
Dim fontt As New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold or FontStyle.Italic)
```

and to use the `StringFormat`, you have to use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d3thd43b.aspx) of `DrawString` that accepts an `StringFormat` parameter:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, fontt, Brushes.Silver, 10, 10, format)
```

Comment: oh yea, with the font and format, but I have many fontstyle in one rtf, should I use a font variable for each line of the rtf?

Comment: So you have a RichTextBox with arbitrary text and formatting and you want to simply copy its current content into an image?

Comment: yup thats right, just want to make the copy whole text into a graphic